# My NFT token Metadata is not opened by Opensea

Tags: metadata, ipfs, opensea, tokenuri

I have the following metadata:

```
{
  "name": "Reallabor Collection",
  "description": "Friends NFT",
  "image": "ipfs://QmYk9C6RJeejmfkBkvSoziSbhkr5fcWt9mmyfegRvAFyZo",
  "edition": 1,
  "attributes": [
   {
  "trait_type": "Status",
  "value": "Friends"
   },
 {
  "trait_type": "Background",
  "value": "Beige"
 }
               ]
}
```

This JSON file is stored on IPFS and on my server.

The link to IPFS is ipfs://ba....

The link to my server is https://stromz...1.json

Bot links work and open the JSON file. However Opensea only shows an image and metadata of the NFT which metadata is stored on IPFS.
If I provide urilink to my server, opensea doesn't show neither the image, nor the metadata.

My question is, is there any reason why Opensea prevents opening links which are not from IPFS or what may cause the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After few days spent looking what may cause the problem, I finally solved it.
So a short intro first. This issue is normally caused, because your JSON file is wrong. It may be a typo or you created an array using [] or you may have added an extra ,

So first be sure that your JSON file is correct. If not, try copying it from another collection where it is working correct.

I did exactly that, I used an old JSON file from previous collection, which was working fine when loaded from ipfs, but this time I had to deploy it to my server, and Opensea had to read it from there.

This is when the problem started, Opensea was not fetching the image and the Metadata, despite being sure that everything in the file is correct.

I texted on the Discord of Opensea and I was informed that if CloudFire is blocking the requests from Opensea, so you might consider that as well, if you are using CF. However in my case I didn't have it.

So the problem was somewhere else, I kept reading and searching until I found this article: https://medium.com/web-design-web-developer-magazine/quick-hack-to-refresh-opensea-metadata-on-many-nfts-quickly-6b8a2a52b080

It sounds so simple, but I never did it. I have never refreshed my metadata from Opensea locally. And that was it, I had to go to Opensea, refresh, wait for few seconds and reload the website. That caused my image and attribute to reappear again. I still don`t know why Opensea doesn't implement it automatically for every new NFT, but if you can not find any solution, consider doing this as well.